# while loop in seperate thread continues running after condition has been changed via seperate method in main thread

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public void taskInProgress(String jobMessage) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runningTask = true;
                Test:
                while (runningTask) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < runningStars.length; i++) {
                        System.out.print(runningStars[i].concat(" ").concat(jobMessage));
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public void taskFinnished(String msg) {
        this.runningTask = false;
        System.out.println("\r".concat(ok(msg)));
    }
```

The wished effect is, that stars get printed as an infinite progress bar in the console, that is the `for` loop nested in the `while` loop, and when i call a method, the stars get replaced with a status and message, and they get stopped. I implemented this with latching the class field `runningTask` in `taskFinnished()`.

My problem is, even after breaking the `while` loop, stars still get printed to the console. The loop continues execution even after the `while` loop condition returns false, for a good few seconds.

Screenshot:

[image]

As seen here, it still says `Extracting tar archive`, after the `taskFinnished()` method has been called and the while loop broken.

Here is the code that uses these implementations:

```
            tc.taskInProgress("Extracting tar archive");

            // do long operation on main thread, keep console animation running in seperate thread, and return exit int, Unix style

            if (exit == 0) {
                tc.taskFinnished("Tar finished without errors");
           // This breaks the while loop, but more stuff gets printed even after breaking loop
            } else {
                // failed, handle it
            }
```

Comment: More than likely, the issue is that you need to make the definition of runningTask `volatile boolean runningTask`. (Add the volatile keyword).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
for (int i = 0; i < runningStars.length; i++)
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < runningStars.length && runningTask; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your boolean flag (`runningTask`) must be declared `volatile`. Otherwise, there is no guarantee that the running thread sees the change made by the main thread.

An alternative would be to use an AtomicBoolean instead. But even better, you should use the mechanism that already exists to ask threads to stop running: interrupting the thread (by calling interrupt() on it). The running thread would have to regularly check if the current thread has been interrupted, using `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`.

The advantage of this mechanism over a custom boolean flag is that it the running thread is blocked waiting or sleeping, it will immediately go out of its waiting/sleeping state, by throwing an InterruptedException.

You should catch that exception, but instead of just ignoring it as you're doing, you should instead stop running ASAP.

Comment: The issue still occurs. No change.

Comment: Turns out, i had to modify the for loop, as hanif pointed out, the boolean latch mechanism was fine.

Comment: Read the remaining of my answer.

Comment: @Gala no, it wasn't fine if it wasn't declared as volatile. You were lucky that it worked, but you might as well be unlucky, and have your thread keep running. You have no guarantee if you don't at least make it volatile. That's another good reason to use interrupt.

Comment: I did put it as a volatile when you pointed it out, I meant fine in a different context.

Comment: OK, then. But you should still read the rest of my answer, and especially, not ignore the InterruptedException as you're doing. If you get an InterruptedException, that means that you should stop running, ASAP.